# Add Textbox and Label From Hyperlink Click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working on a project where my job is to create a basic web data entry form.  I have all the syntax functioning exactly as it should, except now I have the need to have a hyperlink on the page and when clicked add a label and text box.

My questions:

1. Should be simple enough with some JavaScript, however for whatever reason my syntax does not add anything?
2. What do I need to do in order for when the `Add Additional Child` link is clicked it will add a new text box and label?

My `index.php`:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
$("#newChild").on('click', function() {
  $('#ChildInfo').after(
    '<div id="ChildInfo">' +
    '<td><label for="lblChildName">Child Name: </label></td>' +
    '<td class="style1"><input  type="text" name="txtChildName" maxlength="100" size="30"></td>' +
    '<a href="#" id="removeChild"> remove Child</a>' +
    '</div>'
  );
});
$(document).on('click', '#rmChild', function() {
  $(this).closest('#ChildInfo').remove();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="BasicInfo">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="lblParent">Parent Name:</label></td>
            <td class="style1"><input type="text" name="txtparentname" maxlength="500" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="lblPhone">Contact Number:</label></td>
            <td class="style1"><input type="text" name="txtphone" maxlength="500" size="30"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="ChildInfo">
   <label for="lblChildName">Child Name:</label>
   <input  type="text" name="txtChildName" maxlength="100" size="30">
    <br><br><br>
   <a href="#" id="newChild">Add Additional Child</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `.after('<div id="ChildInfo">' ...` is going to be a problem. An `id` _must_ be unique within a page.  Your _ChildInfo_ seems more like a class anyway. Every added input is going to have `name="txtChildName"` which could also be an issue. Multiple controls with the same name will send an array of values instead of multiple name:value pairs.  Good UI also says that something which performs an action should be a _button_, not a _link_.

Comment: @StephenP - I did not even think about that.  Essentially means each time a new is added it will over-write the values from the previous.  Ideally, I would want the name to be txtChildName, txtChildName1, txtChildName2 etc.  I should also limit the number allowed to add...

Comment: For the input `name=` it may be OK to repeat it ... it depends on your situation and what your server expects to be submitted. You could keep a counter `var entryCount = 0`, increment it in your click handler `++entryCount`, and append it to the name, giving "txtChildName1", "txtChildName2" etc... Just something you need to be aware of.

Comment: @StephenP - thank you for bringing that to my attention, if I could upvote you would have it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 2:

Change your event handler assignment ot be dynamic, like you are doing for removing:

https://jsfiddle.net/5n6du1qt/2/

```
  $(document).on('click', '#newChild', function() {
    $('#ChildInfo').after(
      '<div id="ChildInfo">' +
      '<td><label for="lblChildName">Child Name: </label></td>' +
      '<td class="style1"><input  type="text" name="txtChildName" maxlength="100" size="30"></td>' +
      '<a href="#" id="removeChild"> remove Child</a>' +
      '</div>'
    );
  });
  $(document).on('click', '#rmChild', function() {
    $(this).closest('#ChildInfo').remove();
  });
```

-------------- other ways ---------------------

This is because you need to move your script to be called after load event, once the dom is ready.

Please see the working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/5n6du1qt/

You can try changing the script to this:

```
//<![CDATA[
window.onload=function(){
$("#newChild").on('click', function() {
  $('#ChildInfo').after(
    '<div id="ChildInfo">' +
    '<td><label for="lblChildName">Child Name: </label></td>' +
    '<td class="style1"><input  type="text" name="txtChildName" maxlength="100" size="30"></td>' +
    '<a href="#" id="removeChild"> remove Child</a>' +
    '</div>'
  );
});
$(document).on('click', '#rmChild', function() {
  $(this).closest('#ChildInfo').remove();
});
}//]]>
```

**Update:**
Here is one other variation for the script : https://jsfiddle.net/5n6du1qt/1/

```
$(function(){
  $("#newChild").on('click', function() {
    $('#ChildInfo').after(
      '<div id="ChildInfo">' +
      '<td><label for="lblChildName">Child Name: </label></td>' +
      '<td class="style1"><input  type="text" name="txtChildName" maxlength="100" size="30"></td>' +
      '<a href="#" id="removeChild"> remove Child</a>' +
      '</div>'
    );
  });
  $(document).on('click', '#rmChild', function() {
    $(this).closest('#ChildInfo').remove();
  });
})
```

Comment: Don't use `window.onload=` — it will _replace_ any existing onload handler.  Since you're already using jQuery, use `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`  and you can keep it in the `<head>` element with that.

Comment: Right Stephen. I have mentioned other options as well. Easiest being the "on" to attach it dynamically.

Comment: Ah - now that syntax works as it should, is there a way to ensure that the "Add additional Child" text always remain below the newly added label/textbox?

Comment: may be using BEFORE will help you.   $('#ChildInfo').before(